# Reasoning behind Biztalk XPath format

Tags: xpath, biztalk

When you are building BRE vocabularies and need to get the XPath for a node or value, the Schema properties are a convenient source, however the format of those xpaths is a bit jarring.

for something like

```
<ns0:rootnode xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.org">
  <ns0:childnode></ns0:childnode>
</ns0:rootnode>
```

They use the format

```
/*[local-name()='rootnode' namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']/*[local-name()='childnode' namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
```

as I understand it for each node it matches any (*) then in the condition [] extends the conditions to narrow down the nodename and namespace?

I'm no xpath guru by any means, but I'm guessing this is some protection from the namespace prefix changing?

but even with that why not the shorter (and cleaner)

```
/rootnode[namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']/childnode[namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm guessing this is some protection from the namespace prefix
>   changing?

Indeed, this is the [namespace-agnostic](http://jcooney.net/post/2005/08/08/HOWTO-Write-Namespace-Agnostic-XPath-and-XSLT.aspx) Xpath format used throughout BizTalk. This allows a document to be parsed without loading namespaces into an [`XmlNameSpaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx). Also, the use of `local-name()` excludes the namespace prefix (just `childnode`), whereas `name()` includes the namespace alias as well (e.g. `ns0:childnode`).

So the `XPath`:

```
 /*[local-name()='rootnode' and namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
   /*[local-name()='childnode' and namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
```

Can be used to navigate the following xml:

```
<rootnode xmlns='http://mynamespace.org'>
  <childnode xmlns='http://mynamespace.org'>
    .. 
  </childnode>
</rootnode>
```

So

```
/*[local-name()='rootnode' namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
```

Means "navigate from the / to the child with element name `rootnode` and namespace `http://mynamespace.org`", etc. [`*` matches any element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns), and the functions are [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256466%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Unfortunately:

```
/rootnode[namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
   /childnode[namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
```

Won't work, since `/rootnode` cannot be evaluated without the namespace.

Shortcuts are possible, but ill-advised, e.g. if you are adamant that there is only one `rootnode` and `childnode` element across all namespaces in your xml document, you can omit the `namespace-uri()`, i.e.

```
 /*[local-name()='rootnode']/*[local-name()='childnode']
```

But this would break if e.g. if your document looked like so:

```
<rootnode xmlns='http://mynamespace.org'>
  <childnode xmlns='http://mynamespace.org'>
  <childnode xmlns='http://anothernamespacehere'>
```

Also, double slashes are an especially bad idea in BizTalk for large documents, for performance reasons. i.e. avoid the temptation to skip the full path navigation to get to your leaf nodes. This is a bad idea.

```
 //*[local-name()='childnode' and namespace-uri()='http://mynamespace.org']
```

**TL;DR**

IMO, in most instances, the namespace-agnostic Xpath navigations will be generated for you in BizTalk, and you can safely leave them alone. Despite their verbosity, after a short while you'll be used to them and won't really be bothered with them.

Comment: yup, that's pretty clear. thanks - makes it a little less of a nuisance to know the good reason for it.

Comment: Just add, if readability is a concern and you don't expect a name collision (I've never had one), you can drop the namespace predicate and it will work the same.